# SearchDelegate<String> Key board action button press issue

Tags: search, flutter

Search key board action in (`SearchDelegate<>` in flutter). When click search button in the key board it's showing error

I just tried to call Search action button via Search Delegate.

```
class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {

  @override
  List<Widget>buildActions(BuildContext context) {

    return [

      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        width: 1.0,
        color: Colors.grey,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 8.0, top: 10.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 10.0),
      ),

      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.clear,
            size: 30,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            query = "";
          }),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {

    return
      IconButton(
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
          progress: transitionAnimation,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          close(context, null);
        },
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {}

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {

    return Container();
  }
}
```

it's showing an error page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@override 
Widget buildResults(BuildContext context){

return Container(
      //Do what you want to show in the result, when click keyboard action Search.

);
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question, or is it additional code that is part of the question?

Comment: It’s answer for the question

Comment: @VishwaFernando Thank you for providing your answer on your own question. You also may activate the "answered" mark on the answer and accept your solution. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).